# How to get Fortran to warn me if I pass an allocated array to a subroutine with mismatching dimensions?

Tags: fortran

I just spent too much time resolving a bug in my program. I call a subroutine (let's call is `mysub`) defined as:

```
subroutine mysub(hourval,dayval,some,more,args)
use globals
implicit none

real:: hourval(24,ncol,nrow)
real:: dayval(ncol,nrow)

...
end
```

where `hourval` and `dayval` are the arrays that contain the output of the calculations in the subroutine, and `nrow` and `ncol` are integers.

The call to the subroutine looks like

```
call mysub(daygrid,hourgrid,some,more,args)
```

where `daygrid` and `hourgrid` are arrays that were previously `allocate`d. `hourgrid` has 3 dimensions `(24,ncol,nrow)`, while `daygrid` has 2 dimensions `(ncol,nrow)`. All variables mentioned until now (`hourgrid`, `daygrid`, `nrow`, `ncol`) are declared in the module `globals`.

I kept getting strange results and finally noticed that I switched the order of `hourgrid` and `daygrid` in my subroutine call, and changing this solved my problem (the actual variables in my program have less explicit names, which made the mistake a bit harder to spot). However, the program would compile normally, and I would not get any relevant error messages in the logfile.

I'm wondering, therefore, if there is a way to get a message, either at compile-time or at run-time, pointing to that error. I'm using Intel Fortran 11.1 on Linux with the following compiler flags:

```
-O3 -C -pg -traceback -g
```

I was actually counting on the `-C` flag (equivalent to `-check all`) to detect this kind of bugs, as it implies the option `-check bounds`. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Does the call to `mysub` have an interface available?  Or, what is the relationship between the subroutine and the code calling it?

Comment: @francescalus Do you mean an interface as for generic programming? No, that's not the case, the subroutine is called directly from another subroutine (I'm not sure if this answers your question, though). Would you suggest adding an interface as a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The suggestion to use assume-shape is really good (so a +1 there), as that will detect shape mismatches. However, if your arrays have the same shape then you can run again into trouble. The reason is that there is no way the compiler can know what you intended to do if the arguments match what is in the interface.

So, a better solution to avoid the problem might be to use named arguments (in addition to using assumed shape with explicit interface that is). In the example below, `sun` and `moon` are similar arrays that are to be processed. When you switch them around, the subroutine call still works but interchanges the use of the arrays. When using named arguments, no matter what order you put them in, the subroutine will connect it to the correct dummy argument.

```
program named_arguments
integer, parameter :: n = 2
integer, allocatable :: sun(:,:), moon(:,:)

allocate(sun(n,n))
allocate(moon(n,n))

call mysub(sun,moon)

write(*,*) sun
write(*,*) moon

call mysub(moon,sun)

write(*,*) sun
write(*,*) moon

call mysub(night=moon,day=sun)

write(*,*) sun
write(*,*) moon

contains

subroutine mysub(day,night)
integer :: day(:,:), night(:,:)

day = 1
night = 2
end subroutine

end program
```

As you probably give meaningful names to the dummy arguments that reflect their usage, connecting them by name to the actual arguments in the call is a good practice to avoid this kind of problem.

In your case:

```
call mysub(dayval=daygrid,hourval=hourgrid,...)
```

would do the correct thing as using named arguments doesn't rely on the order of the dummy arguments.

Comment: This seems to be the safest way to avoid that problem. Also, I'm always glad to learn about good practice, since I'm picking up Fortran as I go.

Answer (score 6):

You may want to use assumed shape dummy arguments to catch errors like this (i.e `real, dimension(:,:) :: dayval` and `real, dimension(:,:,:) :: hourval`.)

From *Modern Fortran Explained* by Metcalf, Cohen and Reid (2011) :

> Shape, or character disagreement cannot occur when a dummy argument is assumed-shape.

Also, it does not strike me as the most amazing coding style to pass variables already available through the `use` statement as the actual arguments to the same subroutine.

Comment: Indeed, this is a good way to address the underlying programming problems.  It does rely, however, on being able to change the subroutine's defintion, although that is probably fair in this case.

Comment: Sure, the problem is that the standard allows this as you mentioned above. I cannot think of anything which would find already existing bugs like this from the top of my head, short of *maybe* specifying the arrays with total sizes which differ considerably and hoping that a loop over one will crash into the bounds of another at run-time with the bounds check on. (Thanks for reformatting my post)

Comment: No criticism was meant: I find this a good answer.  It's certainly more positive than my answer in that it says how to avoid creating the bug rather than failing to deal with it later.

Comment: Even with assumed-shape arrays, this doesn't get caught by the compiler. Based on this and the other answers, it looks like there is no way to get a compiler warning in this case. To address your side note: I use the same subroutine on different arrays, this is why I pass them as arguments. It makes sense to me, but I don't know if this is good practice - would you do it differently?

Comment: Intel compiler's help ( `ifort --help` ) tells me that flags -e03, -e95 and -e90 instruct the compiler to generate warnings when non-standard code is encountered. It is good practice to test your code robustness with different compilers. Errors not caught by one, might be caught by the other. I use gfortran and ifort for this. My side note has to do with modularity of program design. Telling subprograms only as much as they really need to know, clarifies the design and reduces chance for bugs. Heck, the standard agrees with me, it introduced `only` keyword for that reason, among others.

Answer (score 3):

It could be possible to have this noticed by the compiler at compile time if the array sizes are "known" at that time.  How you manage depends on your code.

If there is an (explicit or implicit) interface available ifort should do this for you without fail.

Even without an interface you may have some joy with the compile option `-warn interface`: this essentially has better-than-usual checking where an interface is "obvious" even if not "available".  [I hope someone can explain better.]

It's possibly worth noting that, unless there is a failing with the interface, the number of ranks isn't necessarily a problem.  Instead it's down to storage extents.  In your case the storages are quite different.[1]

In response to your comment, something about interfaces.

You're already using modules, so if `mysub` is in a(nother) module `use`d by the host of the call then an explicit interface will be available.  This is a good thing to do.  Many details can be found on SO of interface explanations.

Finally, I'll say that even though `hourgrid`, `daygrid` are declared in a module, the dummy arguments by those names are distinct things.

Edit, to be more explicit.

[1] Solving the problem where the dimensions "mismatch" is in general a more difficult problem.  The Fortran 2008 standard says in section 12.5.2.11, when it comes to your subroutine declaration (my emphasis)

> An actual argument that represents an element sequence and corresponds to a dummy argument that is an array is sequence associated with the dummy argument if the dummy argument is an explicit-shape or assumed-size array. **The rank and shape of the actual argument need not agree with the rank and shape of the dummy argument, but the number of elements in the dummy argument shall not exceed the number of elements in the element sequence of the actual argument.**

Your dummies are explicit shape.  So, in general you can't detect a mismatch, but in this case the fact that your dummy `hourval` is bigger (by a factor of 24) than the `dayval` actual argument, is the part allowing your compiler to help.

More generally, one has to be careful when using explicit shape dummies.

Comment: Thanks! `-warn interfaces` seems to be better than the usual settings, indeed (it actually generates the interfaces automatically during compiling). It just helped me spot some mismatches in other parts of the program. It didn't catch this one, though (apparently, regardless of the order in which I compile my files). (I'll upvote your answer once I get the rights to do so)

Comment: OK, that makes sense, `ncol`and `nrow` are read from a file. However, in this case not even the number of dimensions matches, so I'm still surprised that the compiler doesn't catch that.

Comment: That's covered by the "rank and shape" part: the number of dimensions don't have to match for the code to be valid.  The only restriction is on the number of elements, and even then the compiler is allowed to trust that you know what you are doing.  Your wrong code is invalid because it breaks the rule.  In some cases the compiler can be extra nice and tell you when it notices you've made a mistake.  I can't see an ifort option for run-time checking, though.